# Probability question - arranging 20 pupils in a row

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Will someone help me figuring the following out ?

We have 20 pupils in class, 12 girls and 8 boys. 
We arrange the pupils in a row, and now need to calculate the following probability:
The boys will be arranged in two groups, one of five boys, and the other one of three boys, and there will be at least one girl between the two groups ?

Obviously, there are $ {8 \choose 5} \times 5! $ for the first group, and $3!$ for the other group. Afterwards, I can choose a girl to be between the two groups. There are $12$ ways to make this choice. But after that, how can I arrange the other things (i.e.- choose the location of each group etc...? ) ?

Hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at the boys only: [girls]BBB[girls]BBBBB[girls] and [girls]BBBBB[girls]BBB[girls] are essentially different. So a factor $2$ comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $12!$ ways to order the girls and they must be split up
in three groups. The first group have no boys in front of them, the
second have boys in front and boys behind and the third have no boys
behind. The first and third groups are allowed to be empty and the
second group is not. That comes to writing $11$ as a sum of three
nonnegative integers and with stars and bars we find $\binom{13}{2}$
ways to split up. There are $8!$ ways to order the boys and there
are $2$ ways to split up: $3+5=8=5+3$. This leads to $12!\times\binom{13}{2}\times8!\times2$
possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

We now have $14$ objects, $12$ girls and the two groups of boys. These can be arranged in $14!$ ways. But this includes the forbidden configurations where there is no girl between the two groups of boys. There are $(2)(13!)$ forbidden configurations.

So your number (which turns out to be $8!$) that dealt with the boys must be multiplied  by $14!-2\cdot 13!$. With a little simplification this yields $(8!)(12)(13!)$,

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any reason why this number turned out to be different than the other two answers?

Comment: Different approaches, same number.

Comment: You are right. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Choose a girl (one of $12$) to be the first after first boy group (so as to ensure the boy groups are separated) and add her to that group.  You now have $11$ free girls plus the $2$ groups to be arranged in $(11+2)!=13!$ ways.  That makes a grand total of $${8 \choose 5} \times 5! \times 3! \times 12 \times 13!.$$

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any reason why this number turned out to be different than the other two answers?

Comment: It is the same number.

Comment: Yep. Sorry. Thanks  !